# Custom Controls and States

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex4, flash-builder

I've got an `<mx:Button>` in my application, I have 10 items in an XML Node. What I'd like to do is when the button is clicked show the next 5 XML Nodes.

How do I achieve this?

My code is as follows at the mo :

```
<mx:Button x="1380.65" y="582.65" styleName="rightButton"/>
```

The style is just setting the up / over and down states of the button. But I want it to function and show the XML nodes in groups of 5.

Comment: Are you saying you want only five items per page - and you want to go to the next/prev page upon clicking a button?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Got that working just need to do the maths to work out how many items are being pulled and to show / hide the relevant button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you displaying the first five items?

If you're displaying things in a list or DataGrid, I believe you can set the [verticalScrollPosition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#verticalScrollPosition) to scroll the list via a button click.

If you are displaying items using TextInputs, custom component, or other non-renderer-based classes, you just need to manually write some code to update the display elements based on the currently displayed index and what is next.

Can you offer a running sample?  That may us direct you!

Comment: Yeah, its in a HorizontalList.

I havent got an running sample as such, its all running locally due to me working with a database and others.

Can provide the HorizontalList properties tho

Comment: Just an update.. I've set an protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
    // Handle the button
    videoArea.horizontalScrollPosition = 10000;
    videoArea.liveScrolling = true;
   }

But thats just nudging the box over, rather than the items?

Comment: Take your code, give it a hard coded dataProvider to remove backend dependency and give us a simple sample.  I'm pretty sure that liveScrolling scrolls on a pixel by pixel basis. I thought with it off, the list should scroll on an item by item basis.  Otherwise you can do some math based on columnWidth property

Comment: Thanks for the tips Flextras.com seems to work. set the VerticalScrollPosition to 5 and it scrolls through. Just need to do the maths to work out how many items are in the XML etc. Sounds fun =/